What does CSS width: 100% in a flex item do?
Can somebody explain how this css works?
This is my HTML code:


.wrapper {
  display: flex;

  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item-4, .item-5 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: white;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-4">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item-5">Item 5 QR code</div>
</div>



Coding like this will result in the .wrapper box centered the screen. Its flex items: Item-4 and Item-5's width also fits its content, which is as expected.
see this image
And the width of the .wrapper box is 174.86px
see this image
What I don't understand is, if now I add one more CSS code:
.item-4 {
  width: 100%;
}

The width of item-4 suddenly expands to some more width. Its width is measured to be 108.3px.
see this image
How is the number 108.3px calculated from? Why when I add CSS width: 100%, there is just some more space added to the Item-4?

I suspect because width is overriding some of the flex properties and then this issue comes into effect. I'm curious, why are you applying the width: 100%? What are you trying to do?

Here is a step by step illustration to understand what is happening:


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item-4,
.item-5 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: white;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-4">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>

  <div class="item-5">Item 5 QR code</div>
</div>

<p>adding width: 100% and flex-shrink: 0;</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-4" style="width: 100%;flex-shrink:0;">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>

  <div class="item-5" style="flex-shrink:0;">Item 5 QR code</div>
</div>

<p>remove the flex-shrink: 0 to keep the default shrink behavior</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-4" style="width: 100%;">
    <h2>Item 4</h2>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>

  <div class="item-5">Item 5 QR code</div>
</div>



So the item-4 will try to take all the parent width (using width: 100%) but this will push the next item outside so the default shrinking behavior will reduce the width to make both of them fit inside the container.
When item-5 is outside we have an overflow equal to the width of the item-5. The shrinking algorithm will remove that width from both item proportionally.
